# How can i Apply logistic regression in R

Tags: r, dataframe, logistic-regression

I have small data set, i want apply logistic regression on the same to predict myData$Meeting

I am pasting the dput output of my data.frame object

```
myData <- structure(list(Item.Name = structure(c(1L, 14L, 2L, 12L, 2L, 
11L), .Label = c("brinjal", "chocolate", "cold drink", "injections", 
"jeans", "onion", "potato", "shirts", "skirts", "suit", "syrup", 
"tablet", "tee", "wafer"), class = "factor"), Item.Group.Name = 
 structure(c(4L, 
 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("apparel", "food", "medicine", 
"vegetable"), class = "factor"), Quantity = c(44L, 97L, 53L, 
11L, 5L, 71L), Sales.Employee.Name = structure(c(14L, 10L, 8L, 
10L, 5L, 10L), .Label = c("Alysa Fontell", "Breanne Kissock", 
"Clovis Mance", "Eadie Tidcomb", "Ella Tregidga", "Georg Hollyard", 
"Gib Hanalan", "Jade Postle", "Jewelle Woodall", "Kent Franciottoi", 
"Mychal Elix", "Ralina Wraight", "Shaughn Avrahamian", "Sibelle Santino", 
"Sigfrid Alejandro"), class = "factor"), Sales.Employee.Manager = 
structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Hanny Stokey", class = "factor"), 
Sales.Employee.Region = structure(c(2L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L
), .Label = c("America/Chicago", "America/Denver", "America/Kentucky/Louisville", 
"America/Los_Angeles", "America/New_York"), class = "factor"), 
Sales.Enquiry.Stage = structure(c(6L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("Lead", 
"Lost", "Meeting", "Proposal", "Qualified", "Won"), class = "factor"), 
Final.Status = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Closed", 
"Open"), class = "factor"), Enquiry.Source.Sub.Type = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Existing", "IB Call", "OB Call", 
"Reference", "Website"), class = "factor"), Enquiry.Source.Type = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Inbound", "Outbound"), class = "factor"), 
Rate.per.Quantity = c(90L, 130L, 400L, 120L, 400L, 150L), 
Estimate.Value = c(3960L, 12610L, 21200L, 1320L, 2000L, 10650L
), Employee.Gender = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Female", 
"Male"), class = "factor"), Meeting = structure(c(2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, NA), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

when i run this code

```
glm(data = meetingData, formula = meetingData$Meeting ~. , family = binomial(link = "logit"))
```

i get this error,

```
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

Any help will be so thankful & appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> summary(myData$Meeting)
#>   No  Yes NA's 
#>    0    5    1
```

The column you are trying to predict only has values in one of the two classes. This makes it impossible to train a logistic regression.

Comment: so what can you recommended? how can make model better so that i can predict the outcome on new data.

Comment: You will need more data, specifically you will need some observations that fall into the 'No' category. For the regression to learn the difference between No and Yes, it needs some examples of what the No cases look like.

Comment: Thank you sir! I got it. will keep this in mind for further sampling.

Answer (score 0):

Furthermore, your `Sales.Employee.Manager` is a factor with only one level (Hanny Stokey). Because it is a constant, with no variance, it adds nothing to a regression, so if you delete it, the error no longer appears

`myData$Sales.Employee.Manager<-NULL`

Comment: Oh thank you for making me understand. it worked. but it gave additional warning. Warning message:
glm.fit: algorithm did not converge.. what does it mean? And how shall i proceed further?